# Exporting geodatabase using R-Bridge with ArcGIS Pro

Tags: r, arcgis-pro, r-bridge

I am trying to export a spatial points data frame as a Arc geodatabase using `arc.write` function in the R-bridge (arcgisbinding) in R. I'm working in R v3.6.1, ArcGIS Pro v2.4.0 Advanced License, and arcgisbinding 1.0.1.241. The line of code will run for about 10-15 minutes before it fails and throws the following error:

```
> arc.write(path = "C:/Desktop/Geodatabase.gdb/fc", data = LLcoor, overwrite = T)
Error in .call_proxy("arc_write", path, pairlist(data = data, coords = coords,  : 
  insert row failed
```

What's strange to me is that, about a week ago I could export these gdb's with no problems. The dataframe is quite large 350,000 rows and plan to add more. I checked for and removed all `na`'s in my coordinates before creating the SPDF. Spatial Points Data Frame below:
[image: Spatial Points Data Frame to be written to Arc Geodatabase]

I've tried un and reinstalling arcgisbinding, switching my write location, switching computers and clearing my internet cache.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Did you change your ArcGIS Pro install? Please [Edit] to specify the exact Pro release (and the previous release, if appropriate). Any other changes (Windows update, etc.)?

Comment: Thanks for the reply Vince. I edited my question to include the ArcPro install version of 2.4.0 and I have not updated it recently. My systems admin is constantly updating stuff on my machine but I do not think windows, R or Rstudio have been updated recently.

Comment: "What changed?" is still the operative question.

Comment: I agree. That is what I'm struggling with. Are there any known interactions between libraries with arcgisbinding? I edited a column in my dataframe but I cant imagine that edit would cause this to fail.

Comment: But the question is also, what is causing arc write to run for awhile then fail. I haven't been able to find much on troubleshooting this function.

Answer (score 0):

Through more tinkering, I found that my R-Arc linkage was severed.

Be sure to check that the R and Arc linkage is finished. Within ArcPro before opening a project, go to Settings near the bottom of the page. From here, select 'Options' to see a dialog similar to the one pictured below. Select 'Geoprocessing' and at the bottom of that page make sure the correct R version and arcgisbinding version is selected. You can also update arcgisbinding from this dialog (not from R without reinstalling).

[image]